# Solucionar MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648) En Android con MongoDB

Tags: android, mongodb

Tengo una base de datos En MongoDB (y GridFS) en la cual tengo archivos multimedia (Específicamente vídeos .mp4) y estoy tratando de acceder a estos vídeo, la conexión no genere ningún error y cuando quiero extraer imágenes desde la base de datos, me la muestra sin ningún problema; pero a la hora de Extraer los vídeos, La base de datos me devuelve el archivo de vídeo en un ByteArray y este a su vez lo estoy convirtiendo en un archivo temporal para obtenerlo en el videoView de la siguiente forma:

En esta parte estoy trayendo los bytes desde la base de datos:

```
public byte[] video () {

        GridFSBucket gridFSBucket = GridFSBuckets.create(connection.getDatabaseDB(), "test");

        gridFSBucket.find().forEach(
                (Block<GridFSFile>) gridFSFile -> {
                    if ( gridFSFile.getFilename().equalsIgnoreCase("video2")) {
                        setId(gridFSFile.getObjectId());
                    }
                }
        );

        //gridFSBucket.find().forEach();


        GridFSDownloadStream downloadStream = gridFSBucket.openDownloadStream(id);
        int length = (int) downloadStream.getGridFSFile().getLength();
        byte[] bytesVideo = new byte[length];
        downloadStream.read(bytesVideo);
        downloadStream.close();
        //connection.closeClient();

        return bytesVideo;
    }
```

En la siguiente parte estoy obteniendo este byte Array y lo estoy convirtiendo a un archivo .mp4

```
public void procesoVid () {

        try {
            byte [] bitVid = databaseM.video();

            file = File.createTempFile("video", ".mp4", getCacheDir());
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }
            file.setExecutable(true);
            file.setReadable(true);
            file.setWritable(true);
            file.deleteOnExit();

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOutputStream.write(bitVid);
            fileOutputStream.close();

            mostrarVideo(file);

        } catch (Exception ex3) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error 3: " + ex3.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Metodo mostrar video:

```
public void mostrarVideo (File fi) {

        mdc = new MediaController(PruebaMDB.this);
        mdc.setAnchorView(video);
        mdc.setMediaPlayer(video);

        video.setMediaController(mdc);
        video.setVideoURI( Uri.parse(fi.getAbsolutePath()) );

        video.requestFocus();
        video.start();

    }
```

También intente convertir el vídeo con FFMPEG pero realmente no sé como funciona ya que tampoco me funciona ya que me aparece que tiene un error con la posicion del Moov.
El error original que me aparece es este:

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x985916c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x98589380)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Ojala me puedan ayudar, gracia.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93171/discussion-on-question-by-andres-paniagua-solucionar-mediaplayer-error-1-2147).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para los que tengan este mismo error aquí esta la respuesta:
En el método de extraer los bytes de la base de datos, no se debía hacer de esa forma, sino, pasarlo a un file directamente de la siguiente forma:

```
    public File video () throws IOException {

    GridFSBucket gridFSBucket = GridFSBuckets.create(connection.getDatabaseDB(), "test");

    gridFSBucket.find().forEach(
            (Block<GridFSFile>) gridFSFile -> {
                if ( gridFSFile.getFilename().equalsIgnoreCase("video4")) {
                    setId(gridFSFile.getObjectId());
                }
            }
    );


    File file = File.createTempFile("vid", ".mp4");

    FileOutputStream streamToDownloadTo = new FileOutputStream(file);
    gridFSBucket.downloadToStream(id, streamToDownloadTo);
    streamToDownloadTo.close();

    return file;
}`
```